# Switched for number of files changes in a commit

Tags: git

Is there a switch I can give `git log` to see the number of files changes in commits?

Comment: `git whatchanged` will list the files that have been modified with log, not sure if there is a switch that gives you just the count.

Answer (score 2):

An example :

```
git log --oneline --shortstat -n
```

or, alternatively using [git whatchanged](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-whatchanged.html)

```
git whatchanged --oneline -n
```

where `n` is the number of commits in history you want to see.

Answer (score 1):

`git log --stat` will show you the list of which files and how many lines changed.